# Why do Font size and font color button makes CKEditor disappear when I move it to the active toolbar?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

When I move the Font size and color buttons from available to active toolbar CKEditor disappear - why?

Note: I did not get an answer for this question - but I managed to fix the problem halfway by moving the libraries to the www folder (The color button still makes it disappear)

Comment: I provided you a very in depth answer. If it doesn't work, you are not providing enough description of where it is going wrong.

Comment: You also need to install PanelButton so ColorButton can work within CKEditor. https://www.drupal.org/project/panelbutton

Comment: My apologies if I were unclear, my problem was with CKEditor disappearing, not the buttons.
(English not my mother tongue)
Thank you very much for your detailed description for why the buttons disappear

Answer (score 4):

After enabling CKEditor, you have to go into the filter format in the admin that you want to edit, and configure the toolbars to have the buttons and configuration that you desire. It is a bit extreme to call it unusable.

For font color, there is an add on module that provides that plugin integration, [ColorButton](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbutton).

For font size there is [CKEditor Font Size](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_font).

For your original question, there is no way to drop-in a custom build of CKEditor and drop it into your site (that I know of). I suppose it *could* be possible if you use the Editor API and extend and provide it, but there is not a lot of reason to do so.

I am aware that ColorButton only has a dev release, but it is quite functional. I will work at fixing a couple of superficial things and tagging a stable release.

Where ColorButton and others expect to find the plugin:

[image]

Adding the buttons to CKEditor:

[image]

You can then override the list of colors in the option box with your own.

[image]

Also note that ColorButton requires [PanelButton](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelbutton) (a utility CKEditor plugin) as well. It also requires downloading and placing panelbutton in /libraries.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45468/discussion-on-answer-by-kevin-font-size-and-font-color-in-ckeditor).

Comment: It's worth noting that since the colors are added using inline styles, they will be removed by Drupal's XSS filters if the text format has "Limit allowed HTML tags and correct faulty HTML" enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have found your answer but I had the same issue with the CKEditor disappearing when I tried to install the Color Button module. The instructions for the Color Button and Panel Button modules are a bit confusing. You need to install the Drupal modules into the /modules folder but you also need to download the .js libraries from these links below and put those folders into the /libraries folder:

http://ckeditor.com/addon/panelbutton
http://ckeditor.com/addon/colorbutton

Once the .js libraries were installed the CKEditor did not disappear and the buttons worked fine.

Comment: Yes, the modules themselves provide the integration, but you also need to fetch the plugins from ckeditor.com as they cannot be bundled.

Answer (score 0):

I used a patch to solve this issue: Listing down the complete steps below:

1. Install the prerequistes for color button- Panel button [library](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/panelbutton) and [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/panelbutton), UI button [library](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/button) and float panel [library](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/floatpanel).
2. Install color button [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbutton) and copy its [library](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/colorbutton).
3. Listing down the changes in the patch. Goto **/modules/panelbutton/src/Plugin/CKEditorPlugin/PanelButton.php**  and update the path from`$path = '/libraries/panelbutton/plugin.js';` to 
   `$path = 'libraries/panelbutton/plugin.js';`
4. Enable the icon in configuration->Text Editor.